# problems with tinymce style

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

i don't sure why but tinymce delete all

```
<style>
...
</style>
```

info in the textarea

what can i do?
10x

Answer (score 1):

For the record CKEditor isn't a successor to TinyMCE, just a competitor.

You can keep the style tags in the content by specifying 'style' as one of the allowed tags in TinyMCE's validation config. Just add:

```
extended_valid_elements: "style"
```

to the config you pass to init.

Answer (score 0):

`<style>` tags are not valid in the document's body.

It may be possible to protect them somehow (at least it is in its successor CKEDitor, see [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html) and search for `protectedSource`), but the primary question should be: Why are they in there?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using WYSIWYG TinyMCE or CKEditor and framework CodeIgniter version >2.0, you can have problem with dissapearing style attribute.

You set style like  and after submitting the form you get .

Where the hell is style=”” ?

Probably you have this option enable in config.php file :

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

After disabling global filtering , WYSIWYG do not lose styles.

Personally, I did not want to disable this feature so I made a workaround ;o)

Edited based on Bart’s suggestion to not mess with core files ;o)

This security was added for some reason, so to not get rid it completly I created array that store the addresses to which the tag style is not to be removed.

> You need to create MY_Security.php file as extension for core Security
>   class and add modified function _remove_evil_attributes.

```
protected function _remove_evil_attributes($str, $is_image){
  // All javascript event handlers (e.g. onload, onclick, onmouseover), style, and xmlns
  $allowed = array("your allowed url's without domain like '/admin/edittext/'");
  if(in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$allowed)){
    $evil_attributes = array('on\w*', 'xmlns');
  }else{
    $evil_attributes = array('on\w*', 'style', 'xmlns');
  }

  if ($is_image === TRUE){
    /*
    * Adobe Photoshop puts XML metadata into JFIF images, 
    * including namespacing, so we have to allow this for images.
    */
    unset($evil_attributes[array_search('xmlns', $evil_attributes)]);
  }

  do {
    $str = preg_replace(
      "#&lt;(/?[^&gt;&lt;]+?)([^A-Za-z\-])(".implode('|', $evil_attributes).")(\s*=\s*)([\"][^&gt;]*?[\"]|[\'][^&gt;]*?[\']|[^&gt;]*?)([\s&gt;&lt;])([&gt;&lt;]*)#i",
      "&lt;$1$6",
      $str, -1, $count
    );
  } while ($count);
  return $str;
}
```

source: http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/codeigniter-202-tinymce-or-ckeditor-style-attribute-lost-after-update/#comment-543